# Programmers blog promo image issues

Tags: bug, design, site-promotion

Most side panel advertisements/promotions that I recall have a non-white background.  However, https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ihs34.png (Programmer blog promotion) has a white background.  When compared against the background on Programmers.SE (#f7f7f7), this shows a subtle but noticeable difference (a part of the screen looks oddly cleaner than the rest).

Suggestions:

- Make it transparent
- Make it the same color
- Use a substantially different color (example: the Parents.SE promotion)
- Use a border around the image to set it off (example https://i.stack.imgur.com/yYx5g.png )

Not related to the color, but if someone is going to change it...

- The left hand side of the image image appears to be filled wrong (a bracket like thing?)
- The bottom right of the 'table' has two lines of pixels that are anomalous from the banner
- The font is lighter than 1px in places (might be rectified with bolding it)
- The bottom red 'steam' is cropped sharply while the top one has a 'blunt' endpoint.

Comment: The blog ad is a [community promotion ad](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/2635/community-promotion-ads-2012) created by one of our blog authors. If you can help fix it in any way, please do.

Comment: @YannisRizos I can look at it further when I am on my home machine (tracking down the proper font from css and playing with the gimp isn't exactly what I should be doing).  That said, whoever has the original image (layers, fonts, etc..) will have significantly easier access to fixing the image than I will.

Comment: If you have the graphic design skills, you could also create a new one from scratch.

Comment: @YannisRizos my graphics design skills are... lets say I tend to a utilitarian design when working from scratch.  Given time, I could recreate the one that is there what addresses the issues that I perceive but I'm not a from scratch designer.

Comment: I don't think there's any real issue with the image. Ok, so maybe the background can change - but the other points you raised not related to the colour were probably done on purpose, especially with the "jagged" edges of the "table".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what I came up with:

[image]

I've already posted it in the [2013 Community Ads question](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5347/25936), if you like it you should upvote the answer there, and the ad will start appearing automagically. And if you don't like it... well you should have seen the first draft (I even managed to misspell programmers!).