# Community Promotion Ads - 2013

Tags: discussion, community-ads

As it is December 2012, we are now going to reset our Community Promotion Ads for the new year.

#### What are Community Promotion Ads?

Community Promotion Ads are community-vetted advertisements that will show up on the main site, in the right sidebar. The purpose of this question is the vetting process. Images of the advertisements are provided, and community voting will enable the advertisements to be shown.

#### Why do we have Community Promotion Ads?

This is a method for the community to control what gets promoted to visitors on the site. For example, you might promote the following things:

- the site's twitter account
- cool events or conferences
- anything else your community would genuinely be interested in

The goal is for future visitors to find out about *the stuff your community deems important*. This also serves as a way to promote information and resources that are *relevant to your own community's interests*, both for those already in the community and those yet to join.

#### Why do we reset the ads every year?

Some services will maintain usefulness over the years, while other things will wane to allow for new faces to show up. Resetting the ads every year helps accommodate this, and allows old ads that have served their purpose to be cycled out for fresher ads for newer things. This helps keep the material in the ads relevant to not just the subject matter of the community, but to the current status of the community. We reset the ads once a year, every December.

The community promotion ads have no restrictions against reposting an ad from a previous cycle. If a particular service or ad is very valuable to the community and will continue to be so, it is a good idea to repost it. It may be helpful to give it a new face in the process, so as to prevent the imagery of the ad from getting stale after a year of exposure.

#### How does it work?

The answers you post to this question *must* conform to the following rules, or they will be ignored.

1. All answers should be in the exact form of:

   ```
   [![Tagline to show on mouseover][1]][2]

      [1]: http://image-url
      [2]: http://clickthrough-url
   ```

   Please **do not add anything else to the body of the post**. If you want to discuss something, do it in the comments.
2. The question must always be tagged with the magic [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads) tag. In addition to enabling the functionality of the advertisements, this tag also pre-fills the answer form with the above required form.

#### Image requirements

- The image that you create must be **220 x 250 pixels**
- Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
- Must be GIF or PNG
- No animated GIFs
- Absolute limit on file size of 150 KB

#### Score Threshold

There is a **minimum score threshold** an answer must meet (currently **6**) before it will be shown on the main site.

You can check out the ads that have met the threshold with basic click stats [here](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/ads/display/5323).

Answer (score 22):

[image: MarkdownPad is a full-featured Markdown editor for Windows.]

Comment: Awesome (free & open source) Markdown editor I found through [Super User's community ads](http://meta.superuser.com/a/4892/103952) (Windows only, unfortunately).

Comment: If this were for Linux(or Mono!)  I'd definitely use this. My blog uses Markdown and as it is I have to edit most of my posts in Stackoverflow's editor to see what it'll actually look like and to easily format code

Comment: @Earlz http://dillinger.io/ & http://markable.in/

Comment: This project has had a [major new release](http://markdownpad.com/news/2013/introducing-markdownpad-2/) today, with substantial new features added, along with a paid version. I happily paid for the extra features!

Comment: MarkdownPad 2 ad?

Comment: @Dynamic I'm not entirely sure I'd like to promote the app now that it got a paid version...

Comment: From my initial look at the site, it looks like MarkdownPad 2 turned it from FOSS to shareware.

Comment: It's .. still an awesome piece of software. I don't see an issue promoting it.

Answer (score 19):

[image: Programmers Community Blog]

Answer (score 18):

[image: robotics stack exchange]

Answer (score 17):

[image: robotics stack exchange]

Answer (score 15):

[image: Debian -- The Universal Operating System]

Answer (score 13):

[image: Follow us on Twitter!]

Comment: This is a demonstration post to indicate how this should look when an ad is posted. It also doubles as your twitter ad, but it's up to you if you wish to promote it by voting.

Comment: I'd prefer to see an ad encouraging people to share using their own Twitter account, as people are generally more interesting than bots. I think Jeff Atwood said something to that effect...

Answer (score 12):

[image: Cryptography Stack Exchange]

Answer (score 11):

[image: ØMQ \zeromq\ Distributed Computing made Simple]

Answer (score 10):

[image: Tagline to show on mouseover]

Comment: We're looking to [expand our scope](http://meta.writers.stackexchange.com/q/637/26) to more explicitly include tech writing, so I though this site would be appropriate for this.

Answer (score 7):

[image: writeLaTeX.com - Free online collaborative LaTeX editor with Integrated Rapid Preview]

Comment: This is an ad from TeX SX, which may also be useful here. WriteLaTeX is basically Etherpad + LaTeX; it lets you work collaboratively on LaTeX docs with an instant preview of the compiled output. It also works on tablets, where there are limited alternatives. Happy to let the community vote decide on the ad - I'm one of the developers of writeLaTeX, so any feedback appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 6):

[image: Donate to fellow Mogrammers!]

Comment: At the moment there's no Movemeber team for programmers.SE, but I will set one up later on in this year and spread the word for Mo Bros and Mo Sistas to join up.

Answer (score 2):

[image: Crazy On Tap]

Comment: Crazy on tap is a Community of IT professionals. Where we discuss a wide range of topics. (Not strictly limited IT.) It's an Open, Free anonymous forum. Many things that are off topic here can be discussed there.

Comment: Joel S. Discuss COT in this SO Pod Cast. http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/12/se-podcast-30-robert-cartaino-rebecca-chernoff/